# Downloaded Json files from Facebook or Instagram but doesn't look right?

Tags: json, facebook, utf-8, instagram

I downloaded some json files from Facebook and Instagram, most of them are about chatting records.

I found that every non-english characters is formed of something like this "\00HH".  (ex: \u00e6\u00bb\u00b4\u00e5\u0085\u0092).

After some research, I figured out that this is just utf-8 code and decoded all of them, but I am still curious about why Facebook or Instagram didn't decode this for the users?? It seems that Facebook intends to do that??(but I can't find a reason)

Comment: The JSON files were generated incorrectly.  The strings represent Unicode code points as escape codes, but are UTF-8 data decoded as Latin1. For example, the example data if loaded with a JSON library, encoded with Latin1 (to undo the error) and decoded with UTF-8 produces`滴兒`.  You should show the code that produces this data, in case it is your download method that is the source of the error.

Comment: When you said "I figured out that this is just utf-8 code and decoded all of them", can you be more specific? What did you do specifically? I'm having a similar issue (from Instagram json data).